# How to use the CREATE LOGIN sql statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

How to use the `CREATE LOGIN` statement on SQL Server 2005?

I've tried nearly everything: with commas, without them, with strings, without them, etc.

```
CREATE LOGIN @loginame WITH PASSWORD = 'pass', 
DEFAULT_DATABASE='dbname' DEFAULT_LANGUAGE='us_english', CHECK_POLICY= OFF;
```

I always get this error:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a
>   common table expression or an xmlnamespaces clause, the previous
>   statement must be terminated with a semicolon.

Comment: I don't think `CREATE LOGIN` works with variables. You have to use fixed values, or dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The best way is to use above statements but as a string, and then evaluete/exe this string as a command.

Answer (score 8):

Do u want this Create login to be dynamic? Because u say @loginname?

I tried this code and it works for me..

```
CREATE LOGIN test WITH PASSWORD = 'pass', DEFAULT_DATABASE = [enter database here] , DEFAULT_LANGUAGE = us_english, CHECK_POLICY= OFF;
```

Answer (score 6):

If you're running this in SSMS, you could use [SQLCMD Mode](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174187.aspx) (found under the Query menu) to script the variable for your login name.

```
:setvar LoginName "YourLoginName"

CREATE LOGIN $(LoginName) WITH PASSWORD = 'pass', DEFAULT_DATABASE='dbname' DEFAULT_LANGUAGE='us_english', CHECK_POLICY= OFF;
```