# Is it truly possible to create a SQL login using Dynamic SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, dynamic-sql

This is a duplicate question of the one found here:
[How to use CREATE LOGIN sql statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3854694/how-to-use-create-login-sql-statement)

I'm asking this again because I've tried what people suggested in the answers to the question above, and also tried what's in my Murach SQL Server book, but it's not working. Am I running this script correctly or is it impossible to create logins with dynamic SQL? Here's my code:

```
USE MyGuitarShop
IF OBJECT_ID('Admin_For_Login') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE Admin_For_Login;
GO
SELECT FirstName, LastName INTO Admin_For_Login FROM Administrators;

DECLARE @FirstName varchar(50), @LastName varchar(50), @NewUser varchar(100), @ExecVar varchar(1000); --variable to replace login name should be a varchar
DECLARE Administrator_Loop_Cursor CURSOR
DYNAMIC
FOR
    SELECT FirstName, LastName FROM Admin_For_Login;
OPEN Administrator_Loop_Cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM Administrator_Loop_Cursor INTO @FirstName, @LastName;
--PRINT @FirstName + @LastName;
SELECT @NewUser = @FirstName + @LastName;
--PRINT @NewUser + ' - this is NewUser';

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
--FETCH NEXT FROM Administrator_Loop_Cursor INTO @FirstName, @LastName;
IF (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
BEGIN
SELECT @NewUser = @FirstName + @LastName;
PRINT @NewUser + ' - this is NewUser';

SET @ExecVar = 'CREATE LOGIN @NewUser WITH PASSWORD = ''temp'' MUST_CHANGE, ';
SET @ExecVar = @ExecVar + 'DEFAULT_DATABASE = MyGuitarShop;';
SET @ExecVar = @ExecVar + ' CREATE USER @NewUser; ';
SET @ExecVar = @ExecVar + 'ALTER ROLE OrderEntry ADD MEMBER @NewUser;';
EXEC (@ExecVar);
FETCH NEXT FROM Administrator_Loop_Cursor INTO @FirstName, @LastName;
END;
IF NOT(@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
BREAK;
END;
CLOSE Administrator_Loop_Cursor;
DEALLOCATE Administrator_Loop_Cursor;
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change this part

```
SET @ExecVar = 'CREATE LOGIN ' + quotename(@NewUser) + ' WITH PASSWORD = ''temp'' MUST_CHANGE, ';
SET @ExecVar = @ExecVar + 'DEFAULT_DATABASE = MyGuitarShop;';
SET @ExecVar = @ExecVar + ' CREATE USER ' + quotename(@NewUser) + '; ';
SET @ExecVar = @ExecVar + 'ALTER ROLE OrderEntry ADD MEMBER ' + quotename(@NewUser) + ';';
```

and perform a PRINT @ExecVar to verify before executing it

Comment: the issue is not realy due to quotename. But you can't use a variable in CREATE LOGIN / USER . You need to concatenate it to form the CREATE LOGIN command. Using quotename is to ensure that if you have space within the @NewUser, it does not cause any  issue